# SSRS - Rectangle grouping (Multiple tables with different dataset in one rectangle)

Tags: reporting-services, rectangles, ssrs-grouping

I would like to design a report that has multiple tables (different datasets) in a rectangle and the rectangle is showing data which is grouped by company. Could anyone advise on this?

Please feel free suggest other solution if my proposed solution is not ideal.

Sample output:

[image: sample output]

Thanks!!!

Choo

Comment: You can edit one data set . Make JOIN query for all tables and . Use this dataset for your  report

Comment: Since your report seems to have a single master/detail, I would also prefer a single dataset, which will make report design more simple and better performing. I would use rectangle grouping when there is one master with two or more detail datasets and join is not an option due to different detail cardinality e.g. Order header, Order item detail, Order comments detail, Order payment detail

Comment: Thanks for both of your reply but that is just a sample screenshot, my real report is much more complicated, where there are10 datasets with different columns in the table. The only similar thing is these 10 datasets are showing data for one company only. For example: Company details, Employee, Shareholders, Share Transactions, Bank Account, Assets and so on...